# Why am I unable to call this method inside of Javascript Aframe.registerComponent?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to pause the rendering of an `a-entity` with a custom function that utilizes the `.pause()` method. Here is my Aframe component:

```
<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('intro', {

    schema: {
      array: { type: "array", default: ["Hi! I'm Ducky and welcome to", "Black", "Duck"] }
    },

    init: function() {
      const self = this;
      pauseTextRender(self);
    }

    function pauseTextRender(component) {
      component.pause();
    }  
 });
</script>
</body>
```

This is bare minimum. When I check the console I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`. I'm not too familiar with Javascript but how can I make an acceptable function for the Aframe class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript Syntax is incorrect. Which is why you are getting the syntax error. Try doing something like this:

```
,
/**
 * Setup fade-in + fade-out.
 */
setupFadeAnimation: function() {
  var data = this.data;
  var targetEl = this.data.target;

  // Only set up once.
  if (targetEl.dataset.setImageFadeSetup) {
    return;
  }
  targetEl.dataset.setImageFadeSetup = true;

  // Create animation.
  targetEl.setAttribute('animation__fade', {
    property: 'material.color',
    startEvents: 'set-image-fade',
    dir: 'alternate',
    dur: 500,
    from: '#FFF',
    to: '#000'
  });
}
```

Notice the comma which would be after your init function and the way I declare the function setupFadeAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question - `unexpected token: function` is because your `pauseTextRender` declaration is incorrect in this context.  It would be absolutely correct in a different context but, for this one, you need to do :

```
pauseTextToRender: function(component){
    component.pause();
}
```

So your entire registration would look like :

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('intro', {

    schema: {
      array: { 
        type: "array", 
        default: ["Hi! I'm Ducky and welcome to", "Black", "Duck"] 
      }
    },

    init: function() {
      const self = this;
      pauseTextRender(self);
    },

    pauseTextRender: function(component) {
      component.pause();
    }  
 });
```

(Note the comma after the init declaration as well)

This is because inside an object you have pairs like so :

```
{
    name: "value",
    anotherName: "another value"
}
```

...and what was happening for you was that you were giving the value `function pauseTextRender(component){ ...etc... }` without giving the name, and not separating your declarations with a comma.

Hope that helps!